# ActiveRecord select columns where one column is an array of a single property from a relation

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  # id
  # name
  # url

  has_many :floors
end

class Floor < ActiveRecord::Base
  # id
  # building_id
  # name
  # number

  belongs_to :building
end
```

I want to add a method to the Building model that returns the following:

```
def self.some_stuff
  [{
    id: "81b0bd96-20e9-4f01-9801-59f3d9b99735",
    url: "http://www.google.com",
    numbers: [4,5,6,7,8,9]
  },
  {
    id: "5de096dd-f282-41cc-8300-b972fb61ea41",
    url: "http://www.yahoo.com",
    numbers: [2,7,11]
  }]
end
```

Ideally I would like to make this chainable so that I could do the following:

```
Building.all.limit(100).some_stuff
```

**EDIT 1:**

Here is how what I am trying to get at looks like in postgresql:

```
SELECT
    B.id,
    B.url,
    array_agg(F.floor_number) AS numbers
FROM
    buildings AS B
    LEFT OUTER JOIN floors AS F ON
        F.building_id = B.id
GROUP BY
    B.uuid;
```

**EDIT 2:**

The following gives me the data I want but in a really crappy format (because of pluck). If I change pluck to select it breaks.

```
def self.some_stuff
  fields = "buildings.id, buildings.url"
  joins(:floors)
    .includes(:floors)
    .group(fields)
    .pluck("#{fields}, array_agg(floors.floor_number)")
end
```

Comment: Sorry, but a bit more context would be helpful here. What does the `Location` class do, exactly? Can you give an example input and output, using the models you've specified up there?

Comment: Sorry, misnamed that class. `Location` should be `Building`. See the updated question.

Comment: Gotcha! That makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You likely want your `some_stuff` method to look something like this:

```
class Building
  def self.some_stuff
    map do |building|
      {
        id: building.id,
        url: building.url,
        numbers: building.floors.pluck(:number)
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I would like to avoid the n+1 query.

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.some_stuff
  includes(:floors).map do |b|
    {
      id: b.id,
      url: b.url,
      numbers: b.floors.map(&:number)
    }
  end
end
```

Slight modification of Josh's answer. Added the `includes` and changed `pluck` to `map` to avoid n+1 queries.